# Disable Advertising ID collection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase has a page "[Disable Analytics Collection](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics)", which has a section "Disable Advertising ID collection":

> If you wish to disable collection of the Advertising ID in your
>   Android app, you can set the value of
>   google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled to false in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag.

- What exactly is meant by "collection"? Is it still possible to get the ad id and send ads if this is disabled?
- Why is this instruction in the analytics section of firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you are reading is definitely about Google Analytics for Firebase.  I don't know what else you're expecting it to be about.  Perhaps you misunderstand the term "Advertising ID".  For use with Firebase, this doesn't refer to sending advertisements using some advertising SDK.  It's the term used to determine a demographics for the user using your app.  Analytics uses this ID to attach the demographics information to the events that are collected.  If you disable the collection of the Advertising ID, then you will just no longer have demographics data in the Firebase console related to analytics.  It will not stop ads from being displayed by other SDKs that display advertisements.

Comment: If an app shows ads and uses Advertising ID for targeting but uses a custom app- specific ad platform (does not use i.e. AdMob) then the affect of disabling Advertising ID collection is: A. no longer having certain data analytics in the Firebase console that is based on advertising id events OR B. our custom code/ad platform is in some way restricted from accessing the advertising id?

Comment: The instructions on the page you listed only affect Firebase Analytics.

Comment: But the field is named google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled. The other fields on the page have Firebase in the name. Is that a legacy thing or is there some other reason for the name difference?

Comment: I might be wrong about this.  The documentation is not fully clear.  I'm looking in to it.

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific.  Advertising ID just basically includes demographics info in your analytics dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately, I'm not getting this same answer from Firebase support, which seems to say it refers to general google advertising id collection for the purpose of targeting - not specific to what's shown in the firebase console. The lack of consensus is a concern for me. I'd **greatly appreciate** if you got in touch with those folks. My ticket title is "Disable Advertising ID collection". If you can't find it, I've followed CodingDoug. If you follow me back fischdeezy temporarily, I can dm you a link to my support ticket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188121/discussion-between-lf215-and-doug-stevenson).